# Why is "Save all attachments" greyed out on email with many attachments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I've received an email with many attachments. I want to save them all at once - but "Save all attachments" is grayed out, with no clue as to why.

[image]

[image]

Details:

- Office for Business 2016, Windows
- Email account is an Exchange account
- There's no tooltip or other clue on the greyed out button

I can't think of any more details to add. The only non-standard thing about my setup is, I'm on a metered connection (with Outlook set to be allowed to use it) and I set Outlook's download preferences to only download headers at first to save data. But I've downloaded the whole of this email.

I'd like to find out what's disabling "Save all attachments" and find a way to un-disable it - I often receive emails with many attachments and I prefer to download them all this way.

Comment: Which tab specifically is the "open, quick print, ect." on?

Comment: Just at a glance, it seems like its because you have a single file selected. have you tried the toolbar button when the email is open in preview, but no attachments are selected?

Comment: Confirmed in Office 2010+ but there is a work around -> "select all" -> "save as".  If you open the email, then you can use `save all` if you want appears to be just a bug with the preview pane

Comment: @FrankThomas It's the "Attachments" tab, and both it and the drop-down menu are only visible when I have an attachment selected. I can't find any way to select more than one attachment, and 2016 doesn't seem to have a "select all" option for attachments

Comment: As I said open the email in its own window.  At that point you can hit "save all" it appears to be an limitation of the preview pane itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in "preview" mode, you can't "save all attachments".

Open the email in a separate window and the "save all attachments" should work.  Also, in "preview" mode you can't select multiple attachments and just do a "save as".

Answer (score 1):

With Office 2016 Pro Plus, despite "Save All Attachments" being grayed out, I discovered that after selecting all attachments I can use "Save As" and works as if I'd used "Save All." For practical purposes Outlook seems to have merged the functions of the two "Save" options into one "Save" menu item.  I think my office PC may still let me Save All Attachments so this may well be a patch that changed the behavior.

These other comments brought me to try this--thanks all.